# MySQLi not update in this program how can i solve this error

Tags: php, html, mysqli

This code one field problem. That files in int but values get in varchar. so how to change the join query.

```
  <?php 
include 'dblayer.php';
$action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";
if($action == "update")
{ 
    $query = "update employee
    INNER JOIN department ON employee.department=department.dept_id SET
    fname = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fname'])."',
    lname  = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['lname'])."',
    dept  = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['department'])."',
    where id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";
    if( $mysqli->query($query) )
     {
        echo "<script>alert('employee Data updated successfully!')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('view.php')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Database Error: Unable to update record.";
    }
    }
    $query = "SELECT  employee.id, employee.fname, employee.lname,    department.department from employee INNER JOIN department  ON  employee.department = department.dept_id where employee.id='".$mysqli-    >real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."' limit 0,1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query );
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $lname = $row['lname'];
    $dept = $row['department'];
   ?>
```

Department field primary key and employee table id primary key

Comment: DEPARTMENT FIELD ONLY NOT WORKING

Comment: Please try to explain your question in a more intelligible English. This way, it's unreadable.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you passing VARCHAR to a db field that only accepts INT?

Comment: Update query not working. Because dept filed in int but values get in varchar. so how can i pass values and get in to store database

Comment: `you said Department field primary key` and in your query you are trying to update that, it will never happen

Comment: _Maybe_ you want to type cast some value using `intval($value)` or `(int) $val` and leave away the quote chars around it in the query?

Comment: i want store int values but get varchar value only. this is join used

Answer (score 0):

i don´t unterstand your question to 100% but i will try to help you.

first of all - the id of a tabel are primary and auto increment so it makes no sense to update this row

secondly to compare this two rows in a INNER JOIN they database rows must have the same INT attributes

```
employee.department=department.dept_id
```

is in this row employee.department the ID from the department.dept_id ???

thirdly change the code to

```
 where employee.id
```

Comment: department is foreign key.